# Standalone XULRunner Application ProgressListener

Tags: xul, xpcom, xulrunner

I'm developing a standalone XULRunner application, in which its important to give a user feedback on what is happening when a page is loading. My first implementation was guided by the [MDN tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/On_page_load). However, this could only work with pages that I open from my code. I had no way of giving a user feedback for links in the body of a document. Further search landed me at [a forum thread](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?t=607425). Following what this guy did, I could listen to page loading events including state changes, progress changes, and URL location changes. I can now tell when a page starts to load so that I can display the progress bar. I can also tell when the page is fully loaded so that I can hide the progress bar. My code is as shown below:

```js
var myExt_urlBarListener = {
    QueryInterface: function(aIID)
    {
       if (aIID.equals(Components.interfaces.nsIWebProgressListener) ||
       aIID.equals(Components.interfaces.nsISupportsWeakReference) ||
       aIID.equals(Components.interfaces.nsISupports))
     return this;
     throw Components.results.NS_NOINTERFACE;
   },

   onLocationChange: function(aProgress, aRequest, aURI)
   {
     myExtension.processNewURL(aURI);
   },

   //onStateChange: function(a, b, c, d) {},
   onStateChange: function(aProgress, aRequest, aFlag, aStatus) {
      const STATE_START = Components.interfaces.nsIWebProgressListener.STATE_START;
      const STATE_STOP = Components.interfaces.nsIWebProgressListener.STATE_STOP; 

      if(aFlag & STATE_START) {
          document.getElementById("progressBar").hidden = false;
      }
      if(aFlag & STATE_STOP) {
        document.getElementById("progressBar").hidden = true;     
      }
      return 0;
   },
   onProgressChange: function(a, b, c, d, e, f) { return 0; },
   onStatusChange: function(a, b, c, d) { return 0; },
   onSecurityChange: function(a, b, c) { return 0; }
};

var myExtension = {
   oldURL: null,

   init: function() {
    // Listen for webpage loads
    document.getElementById("browser-id").addProgressListener(myExt_urlBarListener,
        Components.interfaces.nsIWebProgress.NOTIFY_STATE_DOCUMENT);
   },

   uninit: function() {
     document.getElementById("browser-id")
       .removeProgressListener(myExt_urlBarListener);
   },

   processNewURL: function(aURI) {
     if (aURI.spec == this.oldURL)
       return;

      // alert(aURI.spec);
     document.getElementById("statusBar").setAttribute("label", aURI.spec);
     // document.getElementById("progressBar").hidden = false;
     this.oldURL = aURI.spec;
    }
};

window.addEventListener("load", function() {myExtension.init()}, false);
window.addEventListener("unload", function() {myExtension.uninit()}, false);
```

I'm wondering if there's a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, using [progress listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Progress_Listeners) is the way to go - that's what Firefox is using to display you status changes while a page is loading. However, I recommend using [`XPCOMUtils.jsm` module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_code_modules/XPCOMUtils.jsm) to simplify your `QueryInterface` implementation:

```js
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/XPCOMUtils.jsm");

...

QueryInterface: XPCOMUtils.generateQI([Components.interfaces.nsIWebProgressListener,
                                       Components.interfaces.nsISupportsWeakReference]),
```

Comment: I'm not a fun of JavaScript but I find this really nice. Not only for progressListeners, but also for a whole bunch of other things XUL. Thanks a lot.